# Question appears "blue"?

Tags: support, design

Some questions are appearing on the main page with a blue background - what does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [encountered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74943/how-do-i-remove-a-frequented-tag) the ["frequented tags"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) feature.

If you don't set any "interesting" or "ignored" tags by hand the system will eventually attempt to guess what you are interested in from your history; these are your "frequented tags" and they are highlighted for you in the various question list views.

You can make it go away by setting some tags as "interesting" or "ignored", though that will give you a different type of highlighting.