# "Highlighted" Questions in the recent or newest list?

Tags: support, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question appears “blue”?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/712/question-appears-blue)

What does it mean that certain questions are highlighted by a transparent green background when I scroll on the main page through the "active" or "newest" list?

Comment: Oh darn yes, I`ve not noticed the duplicate question :-( ...

Answer (score 1):

Those are the ones tagged with one of the tags you selected as favorite.